# Return elements from list that satisfy condition of another list to then compare with a fourth list python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
listA = [230, 232, 230, 229, 237, 212, 245, 233, 220, 230]
listB = [232, 231, 234, 230, 234, 228, 244, 236, 227, 229]
```

How do I compare the lists and only return the points at which `listA` was greater than `listB` into a third list `listC` while preserving the indices so that the result looks like:

```
listC = [   , 232,    ,    , 237,    , 245,    ,    , 230]
```

After all that, there is a fourth list `listD`:

```
listD = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and I am trying to collate it with `listC` so that I end up with list C & D matching in terms of indices:

#### Final Result:

```
listD = [ 2 , 5 , 7 , 10]
listC = [233,237,245,230]
```

I was looking into list comprehension as I was told it would help, but I'm not really sure how to apply what I've read.

Comment: What should be in the indices where there is nothing? A `None`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I was originally trying to assign it as `null` to see if it would be easier to just parse through all non-null values after, but I kept getting "ValueError", so I'm not sure if `None` works differently or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case for [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> from itertools import compress, starmap
>>> from operator import gt
```

Get a new list of booleans where `True` means item in `listA` was greater than corresponding item in `listB`.

```
>>> bools = list(starmap(gt, zip(listA, listB)))
>>> bools
[False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True]
```

Now we filter `listA` and `listD` based on `bools` using `compress`.

```
>>> list(compress(listA, bools))
[232, 237, 245, 230]
>>> list(compress(listD, bools))
[2, 5, 7, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd not use a list comprehension here; you are building *two* lists, not one, and that's just easier with a regular `for` loop:

```
listC = []
listD_filtered = []
for a, b, d in zip(listA, listB, listD):
    if a > b:
        listC.append(a)
        listD_filtered.append(d)
```

Using `zip()` you can iterate over lists in parallel, removing the need to track indices altogether.

You can still use a comprehension here, but then you'd build a sequence with `(a, d)` values, and then use `zip()` again to split that result into two separate lists:

```
listC, listD = zip(*((a, d) for a, b, d in zip(listA, listB, listD) if a > b))
```

This however becomes harder to follow and explain, and you actually have *tuples*, not lists, in that case (depending on your usecase you'd have to convert those to lists again).

Demo:

```
>>> listA = [230, 232, 230, 229, 237, 212, 245, 233, 220, 230]
>>> listB = [232, 231, 234, 230, 234, 228, 244, 236, 227, 229]
>>> listD = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> listC = []
>>> listD_filtered = []
>>> for a, b, d in zip(listA, listB, listD):
...     if a > b:
...         listC.append(a)
...         listD_filtered.append(d)
...
>>> listC
[232, 237, 245, 230]
>>> listD_filtered
[2, 5, 7, 10]
>>>
>>> listC, listD = zip(*((a, d) for a, b, d in zip(listA, listB, listD) if a > b))
>>> listC
(232, 237, 245, 230)
>>> listD
(2, 5, 7, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the result by list comprehension:

```
In [6]: listC = [i for i, j in zip(listA, listB) if i>j]                                                                                                                                            
In [7]: listC                                                                                     
Out[7]: [232, 237, 245, 230]

In [9]: listD = [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(listA, listB), 1) if a>b]                                                                                                                         
In [10]: listD                                                                                    
Out[10]: [2, 5, 7, 10]
```